# Redirect output from javascript to HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have javascript function that calculates the distance between 'My Location' and another location whose coordinates are fetches from a Data Base. Now, i'm using php to extract data from the database and display the data in a HTML table. I also call the javascript using php. The function executes fine and I get the desired result. However, I now want to redirect this output from the function into the HTML table.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
var latLngA;
function getLocation(coordinates,call_number) {
    //alert("Entering with coordinates " + coordinates + " and call number " + call_number);
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        function(position) {
            if(call_number == 0){
                latLngA = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
            }   
            var latlong = coordinates.split(",");
            var latLngB = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latlong[0]), parseFloat(latlong[1]));
            var distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLngA, latLngB);
            var table = document.getElementById('venue_list');
            var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
            var rows = tbody.getElementsByTagName('tr');
            rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[2].innerHTML = distance/1000;
        },
        function() {
            alert("Geo-location not supported!");
        }
    );
}
</script>
<?php
$i = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                    {
                        $name = $row['NAME'];
                        $img = $row['IMAGE_SRC'];
                        $addr = $row['ADDRESS'];
                        $location = $row['LOCATION'];
                        $coordinates = $row['COORDINATES'];

                        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>map_function('{$addr}','{$name}','{$img}','{$i}');</script>";
                    ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $img.".jpg"?>" height="100" width="100">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <?php echo $name?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                    <?php echo "<script type='text/javascript'>getLocation('{$coordinates}','{$i}');</script>";?>
                            </td>
                            <td style="display:none;">
                                    <?php echo $location?>
                            </td>
                        </tr>                       
                    <?php
                        $i=$i+1;
                    }
                ?>
```

venue_list is the id of the table in which the data is displayed. Although the function gets executed alright, I am not able to obtain the output in the corresponding table row. Awaiting a solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rows[i] thing seems incorrect.
try giving the td's different id's if youre creasting them by using a loop anyways. makes it easier to access them.